# Templated function that turns a class member function into std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, function-pointers

I have a method that is invoked a lot in my code with this signature:

```
void foo (std::function<void(int)> func, int a) {
  func(a);
}
```

I can easily pass a function like this to the method:

```
static void bar(int a);
foo(bar, 42)
```

Also, if I have a class instance, I can pass my the function pointer to my instance roughly like this ugly snippet:

```
class Baz { 
  bar(int a) {...}
  callFoo() {
     foo(std::bind(&Baz::bar, this, _1);
  }
}
```

However, in my app, I often need to invoke `foo` in places where I hold a pointer to an object that has a valid member function which could serve as an argument to `foo`. I don't really want to give every class that happens to hold a valid pointer a method that invokes 'foo'. In fact, I would prefer that those classes don't even know about `foo`.

I want a method that looks like this:

```
template<class T>
static void callFooSugar(T* ClassPointer, [What goes here?] ClassMethod);
```

So I could do this:

```
Baz MyBaz;
callFooSugar(&MyBaz, bar);
```

Is there a way to write `callFooSugar` without resorting to macros? I am compiling with C++11.

Comment: like [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94f6a143ee63939f) ?

Comment: What's wrong with `foo([&MyBaz](int i) { MyBaz.bar(i); }, ...);`?

Comment: @T.C.: Its too verbose, would like something simpler

Comment: @PiotrS.: That is actually a very nice solution. I wonder if there is a way to get rid of &Baz in the second argument?

Comment: @ThomasKejser: no, you need `&Baz::` to form a pointer to member function

Comment: @PiotrS. Could wrap it in a macro I suppose.. But hoped where was a way to do it only with templates